How to implement iOS localisation by using Unity iOS PostScript
we want to support localisation for some iOS native popup, it should be depend on the localisation part in xcode, but how to maintain this part in Unity iOS postscript?
we have successfully added the localisation lproj files to the project, but the localisation part is still not updated, we can manually drag the plist.strings to the Unity-iPhone to add the localisation, but we want to implement it in post-script to automatically change it.


https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-show-supported-languages-in-appstore/819162/7   we use this thread to add the supported language. but cannot achieve add localisation

You are likely missing some setting in the generated project. How I would solve this: generate the XCode project without adding any localization (i.e. comment out your post processing script). Create a local Git repository, add a proper .gitignore for XCode projects, put the generated project there and commit it. Then manually add all your localizations, save the project and exit XCode. See in git what was changed, then replicate these changes in your post processing script.

I don't think there is any ready-to-use solution for such a task.
However, I'm confident you can modify the project file as it is a text file (to be more precise, an xcodeproj is a directory rather than a file, as you can see by selecting "show package content" in the context menu in the finder).
So:

save your project file anywhere,
add the localization you want to add
use any diff tool to compare two files (kDiff or something like that)
automate this diff in your script during the post process

I've just added manually Catalan localization in XCode and my change looks like that

Finally, we found a solution that worked: using the Unity Localisation Package and adding the iOS metadata.
After adding any string localization, the ios build will add localisation automatically.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.4/manual/index.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.4/manual/iOS-App-Localization.html
